# What prevents the subclassing of vector<> and having at() or operator[] resize the array if necessary?

Tags: c++, vector, stdvector

What prevents the subclassing of `vector<>` and overriding `at()` or `operator[]` to resize the array if necessary?  Specifically I'd like code to work like this:

```
MYvector<int> v;
v[3] = 1;
```

would be equivalent to:

```
vector<int> v;
if ( v.size() <= 3 )
    v.resize( 3 + 1 );
v[3] = 1;
```

I looked into this many years ago and concluded that `vector<>` simply wasn't designed to be subclassed, but now can't remember what the big road block was.

To be clear it's something I'd do it if were basically one new virtual method to write, but not worth doing if I then need to make dozens of other definitions (friend functions? iterators?) as well.

Dialect would be C++17 or C++20, though discussion of earlier or later dialects or vendor dialects would also be of high interest.

Comment: What if it really is a bug if someone were to access `Myvector` out-of-bounds?  Your class would mask such bugs.

Comment: Filling `n` position means that memory for all `n-1` previous positions is available (already allocated for the vector). If you want to avoid it, then you need another type of container, perhaps a std::map

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Considering the alternative is undefined behavior, it's not clear that masking is worse :P

Comment: Don't surprise your audience. Everyone know std::vector, it is well document and everybody is used to read code like `v.push_back(1)` and understand what it does. And what if you say `v[100] = 1` what behavior will you get... you will have to document it and test it andbefore you know it you just add (accidental) complexity instead of reducing it.

Comment: @MooingDuck Yes, but when your calculations return weird results, and you finally figure out that the index used in `Myvector` was going wild, that's a waste of developers time (when they simply could use `vector::at()`).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I agree fully with you. Adding implicit behavior is a nasty thing. That std::map's operator[] does something like this is one of the mistakes in the standard library. A lot of bugs have been introduced by it

Comment: I don't think there are any technical reasons you cannot do this. The only thing sometimes mentioned is the lack of a virtual destructor in `std::vector`, but you aren't going to be allocating this class dynamically anyway. Whether it's a good idea is the issue.

Comment: @OP If you're going down this route of having `[]` do resizing, at least give the user an option to turn off this "feature" and revert to using `[]` as it stands now.  Maybe `Myvector.auto_resize(false);` will turn off the automatic resizing.

Comment: I suppose the biggest issue is that you cannot distinguish between assignment to an out of bounds index and getting the value from an out of bounds index. Also there is the issue of what `size` and `capacity` really mean in this strange vector. It's a bit too strange for me.

Comment: @john *the lack of a virtual destructor* -- I think that may have been what I was thinking of, thanks!

Comment: I'd leave `at` alone. Part of it's contract with the user is it will throw an exception if it goes out of bounds.

Comment: @user4581301 it would still do that.   It would just never be out of bounds so it would never throw.   But that meets the contract of throwing if it's out of bounds.

Comment: Your `MYvector<int>` passed as an argument to a function taking a `std::vector<int>& v` parameter will **not** use your member functions (since they are not virtual, and will not be dynamically dispatched).  If all your code uses `MYvector<int>` and you never have to worry about it pretending to be a `vector<int>`, then you're golden.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie "when your calculations return weird results, and you finally figure out that the index used in Myvector was going wild, that's a waste of developers time" sure, but that applies to raw `std::vector` too, so this proposal is strictly better in that scenario.

Comment: @xaxxon Unfortunately

Comment: Bad idea to do this since 1. `[]`/`at` behaviour would differ between const and non-const versions of the class. 2. Implicit conversion to `std::vector<int>&` is possible, but would change the behaviour 3. The `[]` operator only works for element types with a default constructor (a requirement imposed by the single argument version of `resize`). 4. the behaviour regarding iterator/reference invalidation changes for `[]`...

Answer (score 3):

It is possible by using a class definition like this:

```
template <class T>
class MYvector : public vector<T>
{
public:
    T& operator[](size_t i) {if (vector<T>::size() < i+1) vector<T>::resize(i+1); return vector<T>::operator[](i);}
    T& at(size_t i) {if (vector<T>::size() < i+1) vector<T>::resize(i+1); return vector<T>::at(i);}
};
```

However, it may be better to resize the vector explicitly instead of doing it by calling `operator[]`. Automatic resizing can mask errors, and also the new elements (after automatic resizing) are value-initialized by the default constructor (but not explicitly initialized by the user)

Comment: The new elements added by resize() are initialized with default constructor, aka value-initialized.

Comment: Performance note: Depending on how `resize` is implemented a simple `for (int x = 0; x < y; x++) vec[x] = 0;` could result in  A LOT of reallocations.

Comment: @user4581301 is that true?   https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize that says it's linear to the difference in elements.   Not sure how that's possible if reallocations are such that it would require a reallocation per element added.  Each actual reallocation would be linear to the total elements so if I understand, it has to be amortized by using larger actual memory allocations than exactly what is requested.

Comment: @xaxxon: It's linear *per call*. But the loop in that comment calls it `y` times, so that could be `O(y^2)` copy operations.

Comment: @xaxxon: "Additional complexity possible due to reallocation if capacity is less than count."

Comment: @MooingDuck https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back weird, push_back is guaranteed to be amortized constant.   Which requires at least IT does intelligent resizing (i.e. not minimally incremented each time)

Comment: @xaxxon if I recall correctly, inserting single items, like `push_back` and `insert` (single item) require amorized, but the bulk operations like `insert` (iterators) and `resize` do not.

Comment: @MooingDuck I guess that makes sense... if you had to do some massive resize near your actual memory limits on a system (gigabytes on a 32-bit system or whatever), having it decide to then double that could cause an inability to resize when it should work.  It should allow you to be very specific about sizing when you ask to be.   However, this could be done with pushbacks instead of resizes (for algo efficiency)   or just implementing your own resize.